# how to write the password in order to access my external drive?

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, password, external-hdd

I have an external hard. However, when I want click on it in order to write its password to access it. I get this error

> no .filesystem or .encrypted interface on d-bus object ubuntu

I don't get the password box in order to write the password in it.

thanks in advance

Comment: More info is needed. Is this an encrypted hard drive? How are you trying to access it?

Comment: And, if encrypted, how exactly was it encrypted?

Comment: it is encrypted hard drive. I tried to access it by my windows laptop and it works fine. it is a bit-locker encryption